# Threaded For Loop Function Stuck

Tags: python, multithreading, function, class, python-multithreading

I'm relatively new to python so having trouble working out why i'm hanging on starting my thread. Below i'm trying to start the thread but it hangs on `ticker=threading.Thread`. The code is simulating a trading websocket with hisorical data, I went down the threading route rather than setting up a mock socket properly as its enough for my purposes.

```
ohlcv_strats = ['stratergy 1', 'stratergy 2']
aggregate_strats = ['stratergy 3', 'startergy 4']
if stratergy in ohlcv_strats:
    q = queue.Queue()
    socket = MockSocket(setup, q)
    ticker = threading.Thread(target=socket.ohlcv_ticker(), args=(setup, q), daemon=True)
    ticker.start()
    # ticker result
    ohlcv_ticker = q.get()
elif stratergy in aggregate_strats:
        print('start aggregate ticker')
```

As far as I can work out it seems to be launching the function inside my main thread so I get stuck inside the for loop and am unable to step over when debugging.

This is the class with the function i'm trying to run

```
class MockSocket:
    
    def __init__(self, setup, q):
        self.symbol = setup['symbol']
        self.df_ohlcv = setup['df_ohlcv']
        self.df_tick = setup['df_tick']
        self.q = q
    
    def ohlcv_ticker(self):
        # placeholder dict
        ticker_dict = {'e': '24hrTicker',
                    'E': 1615246586071,
                    's': 'ETHBTC',
                    'p': '0.00133400',
                    'P': '3.958',
                    'w': '0.03415149',
                    'x': '0.03370200',
                    'c': '0.03503400',
                    'Q': '0.35100000',
                    'b': '0.03503100',
                    'B': '0.20900000',
                    'a': '0.03503200',
                    'A': '44.84800000',
                    'o': '0.03370000',
                    'h': '0.03511000',
                    'l': '0.03352900',
                    'v': '384222.79900000',
                    'q': '13121.78030909',
                    'O': 1615160185712,
                    'C': 1615246585712,
                    'F': 239943553,
                    'L': 240321960,
                    'n': 378408
                    }
            
        start_time = self.df_ohlcv['time'].iloc[0]
        tf = (self.df_ohlcv['time'] - self.df_ohlcv['time'].shift(1)).dt.total_seconds().bfill().astype(int).iloc[0]
        r_start = self.df_ohlcv[self.df_ohlcv['time'] == start_time].index.tolist()[0]
        
        # for loop over df for ticker
        for i in range(r_start, len(self.df_ohlcv), 1):
            if i > r_start:
                r_start = r_start + 1
            else:
                pass
            o, h, l, c, v = self.df_ohlcv['open'].loc[r_start], self.df_ohlcv['high'].loc[r_start], self.df_ohlcv['low'].loc[r_start], self.df_ohlcv['close'].loc[r_start], self.df_ohlcv['volume'].loc[r_start]
            o, h, l, c, v = '{:.8f}'.format(o), '{:.8f}'.format(h), '{:.8f}'.format(l), '{:.8f}'.format(c), '{:.8f}'.format(v)
            e = (pd.to_datetime(self.df_ohlcv['time'].loc[r_start]) - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1ms')
            ticker_dict.update({'o' : o, 'h' : h, 'l' : l, 'c' : c, 'v' : v, 's' : self.symbol.upper(), 'E' : e})
            time.sleep(tf)
            self.q.put(ticker_dict)
```

Also open to other options on how I can tidy this up! this is my first python project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
threading.Thread(target=socket.ohlcv_ticker(), args=(setup, q), daemon=True)
```

This is running the function `socket.ohlcv_ticker()` and then making a thread with the *result*. The thread itself doesn't get made until after the function is run. My guess is that you intend

```
threading.Thread(target=socket.ohlcv_ticker, args=(setup, q), daemon=True)
```

Which runs `socket.ohlcv_ticker` in a separate thread.